# How can I see a timestamp for when a command was executed using history?

Tags: bash, history, timestamp

I'd like to check at what time/date a command in bash history was executed.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is possible. The `help history` command says:

> If the $HISTTIMEFORMAT variable is set
>   and not null, its value is used as a
>   format string for strftime(3) to print
>   the time stamp associated with each
>   displayed history entry.  No time
>   stamps are printed otherwise

I set the variable for my user like this (on Ubuntu):

```
echo 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d.%m.%y %T "' >> ~/.bashrc
```

If you want it globally then add the line to `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
echo 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d.%m.%y %T "' >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

See `man strftime` for all possible formatting options

---

The ouput of `history` on my box:

```
  ...
  132  05.05.11 10:45:11 ls
  133  05.05.11 10:45:14 cd ..
  134  05.05.11 10:45:17 history
```

P.S. When you set the variable the first time then the entire history will get the time stamp of the moment the variable was set.

Comment: I'll find this really useful but I haven't had any success yet. I've appended [export HISTIMEFORMAT="%d.%m.%y %T "] to my ~/.bashrc but I'm not yet getting the extra time data when I do `history`. (On Ubuntu 10.10 for what it's worth.)

Comment: @boehj: You might need to log out and log in again

Comment: OK I'll give that a go and report back. Cheers. But for now it's beer-o'clock. :)

Comment: looks great but unfortunately I'm seeing the same as @boehj on Centos

Comment: @Jonathan: I think on CentOS you need to edit /etc/bashrc

Comment: @Jonathan and @boehj: of course, there was a `T` missing from the variable name :( I blame my fingers...I've updated the answer, please try now

Comment: @Slim K - Works a charm now. Thanks for clearing that up. This is going to more than a little useful for me. Many thanks. :)