# How to get commands before timestamps in `history` output in Bash?

Tags: bash, command-history

I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/279451/432690) about time-stamping history for Bash.

**Is there any way to permute the output?** In particular

```
Number command time-stamp
```

rather than

```
Number time-stamp command
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can process the output of `history` builtin. First prepare your `HISTTIMEFORMAT` according to the answer you linked to:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d.%m.%y %T "
```

To get the desired output, invoke:

```
history | awk '{ printf "%s\t",$1; for(i=4; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s",$i OFS; printf "\t%s %s\n",$2,$3 }'
```

---

If you overwrite `history` builtin with a function:

```
history() { builtin history | awk '{ printf "%s\t",$1; for(i=4; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s",$i OFS; printf "\t%s %s\n",$2,$3 }'; }
```

then it is enough to write `history` to get what you want.

Note: leading spaces and column formatting from bare `history` output are lost. Since the *command* field has no fixed length, having it in a middle is not a best idea. I deliberately separated the fields with tabs (instead of spaces) to make the output more readable. If you prefer spaces then replace `\t` in my code with  (space).